# Vue 3 vite multi page app not match found for location with path

Tags: vue.js, vite, multipage

I'm trying to follow this simple basic tutorial on how to add multi-page to my vue app.

- I created a new project (npm i vue@latest)
- Added the nested file:
  [image]

And this in theory should be enough, but it doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well while writing this question, I realized that adding the last "/" to the route was required to make it "/nested/"... so now works, I hope it helps someone.

[image]